# How can I change the stroke-width property of an AmChart graph?

Tags: javascript, php, css, wkhtmltopdf, amcharts

I am generating a report using AmCharts graphs and it works great. The problem comes when I am converting the page to pdf and I get black strokes around each charts' frame. When I check the html I find things like:

```
<path cs="100,100" d="M0.5,0.5 L609.5,0.5 L609.5,549.5 L0.5,549.5 L0.5,0.5 Z"
fill="#FFFFFF" stroke="#000000" fill-opacity="0" stroke-width="1" stroke-
opacity="0" transform="translate(10,0)"></path>
```

I can edit line opacity and line color and it works in html but when I use wkhtmltopdf to convert to pdf these are ignored and I get black strokes around each chart. What can I do to avoid this?

Answer (score 2):

What you're seeing there is a chart background element. It's not seen on screen because it has as a zero opacity by default. I'm not too familiar with wkhtmltopdf (I'm using PhantomJS which does not have that problem) so I'm not sure why it shows border around the background if the opacity is 0, however there is a tricks you could try.

First of all we will need to enable class name application to chart elements, using [`addClassNames`](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/AmSerialChart#addClassNames) property.

```
AmCharts.makeChart( "chartdiv", {
  ...
  "addClassNames": true,
  ...
} );
```

The SVG node in question will then have a `class="amcharts-bg"` attached to it. Now you can target it via CSS:

```
.amcharts-bg, .amcharts-plot-area {
  stroke-width: 0!important;
}
```

Or outright simply hide the whole background if you're not using it anyway:

```
.amcharts-bg, .amcharts-plot-area {
  display: none;
}
```

I hope this is enough to work around the wkhtmltopdf issue.

Comment: It did not work. Here is one of the generated graphs in html
https://gist.github.com/xeppen/67c33fc373f00cc031b7

Comment: Did you add the "addClassNames" parameter? I don't see any classes applied to SVG nodes. So either you didn't add the parameter or you are using some older version of the library, in which case you should probably upgrade.

Comment: Oh no, I forgot that. Updated the gist. But it didn't removed the panels.

Comment: I updated the CSS in the answer. Would you mind trying that as well?

Comment: Still the panels. Nothing changed

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm out of suggestions then :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79529/discussion-between-sebastian-l-and-martynasma).

Comment: Thanks adding the 'addClassNames' parameter and  the 'display: none;' in the css file worked for me.